# Displaying MalformedURLException in JTextArea

Tags: java, jtextarea, malformedurlexception

I am working on Java program having several components. What I am trying to achieve is, that any Exception be displayed in the JTextArea, and not in the console. The code below doesn't work. What can I do?

catch ( MalformedURLException e) { 
                    textArea.append(e); }

Thank you

Comment: How doesn't it work? What does do instead? Can you post more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JTextArea does not support the append() method.
You could try  this if you just need to display the error:

```
catch ( MalformedURLException e) { textArea.setText(e.toString()); }
```

You could try this if you need to append the message:

```
catch ( MalformedURLException e) { textArea.setText(textArea.getText()+e.toString()); }
```